# IF между строками JAVA

Tags: java, строки, сравнение

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String com = scan.nextLine();
    String a = "hi";

    if(com == a){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");

    }
}
}
```

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Если ввести `hi`, то переменная com будет равна hi, но условие выдает `false`. Если еще под `System.out.println("false");` дописать `System.out.println(com)` и `System.out.println(a)` , то в консоли выдаст:

```
false
hi
hi
```

Помогите сделать так, чтобы он выводил true

Comment: Прежде чем мгновенно создавать вопрос, открой поиск и посмотри нет ли похожих вопросов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените `com == a` на `a.equals(com)`. Тогда будут сравниваться на совпадение последовательности символов. Сейчас же сравниваются ссылки на объекты. А они разные, несмотря на то, что последовательность символов одинакова.